# How can I use __coverage__ global object generated by istanbul to get code coverage report?

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

I'm using istanbul to know what lines of code were executed when I perform an operation on my web app. In order to do this I first instrumented the code using:  npx nyc instrument

Then I deployed this code and did my testing. This generated a __coverage__ global object that I have copied into ./.nyc_output/coverage.json

To get the code coverage report, I tried npx nyc report --reporter=html --report-dir=./coverage

However on opening the resultant html file, I see it's empty:
[image: index.html]

What can I do to fix this?